# How to change this notify_one so that it chooses a random thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, condition-variable

Thanks in advance for any help.
Trying to make a program that would create 6 threads, then each 2 seconds randomly choose one and make it print its number. I am obviously doing something wrong, because it just keeps printing 0-1-2-3-4-5 endlessly. The code is below.
Main question is, what should i do to make random threads unlock?

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
std::condition_variable* cv = new std::condition_variable();
std::mutex cv_m;

void threadFunc(std::shared_ptr<bool> flag2, int id)
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(cv_m);
        cv->wait(lock);
        if (true)
            if (*flag2) std::cout << "Thread" << " " << id << std::endl;
    }
}
int main() {

    std::shared_ptr<bool> f2 = std::make_shared<bool>(false);

    std::thread threads[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        threads[i] = std::thread(threadFunc, f2, i);
    *f2 = true;

    while (true)
    {
        cv->notify_one();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Computers aren't good at random. in this case, don't expect random order. There is ordering, if only to prevent the same waiter being woken every time by dumb luck.

Comment: Why are you expecting it to use a random thread? Why does it matter which thread gets notified?

Comment: [Documentation for `notify_one`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one). First paragraph of notes discusses ordering.

Comment: Any series of numbers is random. This is not intended to be random source of any strength so your observation is still good.

Comment: @user4581301 That ordering is about atomicity, not wake ordering. The relevant sentence is the first one: "unblocks one of the waiting threads." It does not specify which of the waiting threads is unblocked, if there is more than one. If you need a specific order, you will need to enforce it yourself (e.g., by adding a variable that keeps track of whose "turn" it is.)

Comment: @Dani, A sequence of numbers is "random" if it's hard\* to predict what will come next. If the program in the example above spits out hundreds of repetitions of "0-1-2-3-4-5," then correctly predicting what will come next is not likely to be much of a challenge.

Comment: \* for some definition of "hard."

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: How do you know it wasn't random to begin with? https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: @Raymondchen Could you show how it's done?

Comment: There are many ways. One is to give each thread a different cv, and then use a random number generator to decide which cv to notify. I'm sure you can think of other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condition variable for each thread, it should be false for each thread at the beginning, then change a random condition variable to true and notify all, this will make a random thread to wake up (the thread that owns that condition variable)
here is the full solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "UserInterruptHandler.h"

using namespace std;
UserInterruptHandler h;
condition_variable conditionalVariable;

mutex mtx;
bool flag = true;

void myMethod(int id, bool *canWork) {

    unique_lock<mutex> ul(mtx);
    while (flag) {
        conditionalVariable.wait(ul,[=]{return *canWork;});
        if(!flag)
            break;
        cout << "thread " << id << endl;
    }
    cout << "thread " << id << " exits.." << endl;
}

int main() {

    cout << "input thread count" << endl;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    thread myThreads[n];
    bool *canWork = new bool[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        canWork[i] = false;
        myThreads[i] = thread(myMethod, i + 1, &canWork[i]);
    }


    while (!h.checkInterruption()) {
        int i = rand() % n;
        canWork[i] = true;
        conditionalVariable.notify_all();
        canWork[i] = false;
        usleep(1000);
    }

    flag = false;
    int i = 0;

    for (thread &th:myThreads) {
        canWork[i++] = true;
        conditionalVariable.notify_all();
        if (th.joinable())
            th.join();
    }
}
```

notice that here I am using header `UserInterruptHandler.h`  to handle CTR+C event to end all threads gracefully